# Databricks-Connect 6.6 doesn't add custom modules to Spark Context

Tags: pyspark, modulenotfounderror, databricks-connect

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour in Databricks-Connect 6.6 and was wondering if anybody has seen this before and knows what causes this problem.

I have created a local Spark Context via Databricks-Connect and can successfully connect to my Cluster and execute any script. But, as soon as I try to add a custom module to my Spark Context via `sc.addPyFile()` and use a custom class/function from it, the execution fails with the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I'm aware of how to add a Python file (or a ZIP file containing a package) to the Spark Context and it worked some months ago when I used an earlier version of Databricks-Connect (I think 6.2 which was depreciated, so I had to update). Also, if I pack the package as a Wheel and install it on the cluster, everything works fine. Actually, even if I add the package to the Spark Context while running the script on a Databricks compute target via Azure ML, it works fine. It just seems to be broken if I use Databricks-Connect.

While debugging, I inspected `sys.path` and the package/module was listed there, so it seems that even though the package is added to the Spark Context, it doesn't get shipped to the worker nodes.

While I first experienced the problem when working with `joblibspark`, it also occurs when I call

`sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4]).mapPartitions(test_function).collect()`

I already tested everything which has been suggested for similar problems and changed all general parameters (Databricks cluster, runtime, local environment, ...) but the error remains and can be reproduced easily by running `sc.parallelize()`... via Databricks-Connect (and providing test_function through a module which is added to the Spark Context via `sc.addPyFile()`.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Some days ago, Databrick-Connect 7.1.0 was released which seems to have solved this issue. I don't know what caused or solved the problem, but if anybody runs into this problem, try to update to a Databricks Cluster with Runtime Version >= 7.1.0 and use the corresponding Databricks-Connect Version.

Comment: One comment Databricks runtime 6.4 is having Long Term Support (LTS) and the higher versions still need time to reach the stability, therefore, you might see anomalies with higher versions. Can you check whether 6.4 meets your need so that you can use it into production without any issue? Once a higher version with LTS comes you can migrate it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that, the last LTS which is displayed if I create a new cluster is 5.5, therefore I wasn't looking at 6.4, but I will check it out! :-)